# Comparing a csv file with file and finding the match is not working

Tags: perl, csv, match

I am comparing csv file with another normal file both the files have lot of similar words(Fields) but it is not matching

```
my $file = "sample.csv";
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";
my $csv1 = Text::CSV->new ({
      binary    => 1, # Allow special character. Always set this
      auto_diag => 1, # Report irregularities immediately
});
my @lines = read_file("brand1.txt");

my $count = 0;
while (my $row = $csv1->getline ($fh)) {
   $count = $count + 1;
   foreach my $line(@lines) {

      my $che = $row->[4];
      print $count;
      if ($line eq $che){
         print $line ."\t". $che;
      }
   }
}
```

This code gives me blank output in terminal.

But comparing two files(without csv file) works with the same script

Comment: Have you considered placing `print "<<<$line>>>\n>>>$che<<<\n";` immediately before your `if ($line eq $che)...` statement to verify that the data looks like you expect?  I'm not sure which `read_file()` you are using, but does it `chomp`?

Comment: ...to be more clear: The first step to determining why one thing does not equal another thing is to look at the two things and see if you can spot a difference.  In your case I suspect the issue is that each line found in `$line` has a `\n` newline at the end.  And your CSV, after being parsed, does not, so they will never be identical. The solution is probably to `chomp @lines;`.  But to be sure, do as I suggested; print the two items that you're trying to compare so that you can see the difference.

Comment: Yeah david thanks it is not chomping before...after editing the script it is working

Comment: Between you can add it as answer to this question

Comment: I've gone ahead and converted the comments to an answer for you. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing one can do when trying to figure out why two things aren't equal is to print those two things.

`print "<<<$line>>>\n>>>$che<<<\n";`

This will show you visually what the differences are, which most of the time will make it obvious.

In your case the issue is that `read_file` doesn't `chomp` input, so each line in `@lines` has a `\n` at the end.  However, your parsed CSV does not.

If you do this:

`chomp @lines;`

It should work fine.